# How to replace characters in a string of 0's and 1's by other characters

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to write a function that takes a string of 1 and 0 and replaces the 1 with "." and the 0 with "_"

I am not sure how to store the new string and print it afterwards

```py
def transform (x):
    text = ''
    for i in range(x):
        if i == 1:  
            i = "."
            text += i
        else:
            i = "_"
            text += i
    return text

transform(10110)
```

Comment: Note that `10110` is not a string but a number. You should write `transform('10110')` instead. Also, to iterate over characters it should be `for i in x:`, without `range`. There is one more little mistake, but you should be able to find it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way: Loop over the string directly and then add the `.` or `_` based on the `if` statement. Make sure you use `i == '1'` because your input is a string. You don't need to modify the value of `i` inside the `if` statements.

```
def transform(x):
    text = ''
    for i in x:
        if i == '1':
            text += "."  # directly add the `.`
        else:
            text += "_"  # directly add the `_`
    return text

transform('11001010') # call the function
# print (transform('11001010'))

# '..__._._'
```

Comment: Right, I see. Thank you!